# to verify the existence of a user in the FireBase database on the Android Studio platform. Java language

Tags: java, android

I need to run a project where a person scans the QR code for each student, and after checking whether there is such a student in the database or not, a window appeared in which you can write a complaint and it would be saved to the same database. There is already a scanner, a database and related windows, I can't figure out how to check for the presence of a student in the database. Help

MainActiviti

```
package com.example.project;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button scan_btn;
    TextView textView;




    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scan_btn = findViewById(R.id.scanner);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text);

        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
                intentIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
                intentIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan a QR Code");
                intentIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE);
                intentIntegrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        IntentResult intentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(intentResult != null){
            String contents = intentResult.getContents();
            if(contents != null){
                ///тест
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecActiv.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                ///textView.setText(intentResult.getContents()); (тут мы выводим расшифровку QR сканнера)
            }
        }
        else{
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }



    }
}
```

SecActiviti

```
package com.example.project;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
///import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

public class SecActiv extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sec);


    }

    public void openNewActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    ///public @NonNull FirebaseApp getApp() {
    ///return null;
    ///}



}
```

User

```
package com.example.project;

public class User {
    public String id, name, second_name, email;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String id, String name, String second_name, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.second_name = second_name;
        this.email = email;
    }


}
```

Oknoviti

```
package com.example.project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Oknoviti extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText edName, edSecondName, edEmail;
    private DatabaseReference mDataBase;
    private String USER_KEY = "User";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.oknoviti);
        init();

    }
    private void init(){
        edName = findViewById(R.id.edName);
        edSecondName = findViewById(R.id.edSecondName);
        edEmail = findViewById(R.id.edEmail);
        mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USER_KEY);
    }
    public void onclickSave(View view){
        String id = mDataBase.getKey();
        String Name =   edName.getText().toString();
        String SecondName =   edSecondName.getText().toString();
        String Email =   edEmail.getText().toString();
        User newUser = new User(id, Name, SecondName, Email);
        mDataBase.push().setValue(newUser);
    }
    public void onclickRead(View view){

    }



}
```